# Finding item values from one list in another list

Tags: python-2.7, list

Im working through a book, and one of the exercises has me trying to match letters in a string to letters in the alphabet, and then shift them forward or backwards a certain amount. Is there any way that I can compare the lists and find the values for items that are the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
if i in string.ascii_letters: # i is item values
# do something
```

I also understand your mind :)